# Best approach to mark specific Rails Models to be used in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to write a lib plugin/extension to perform an action where I need to know which Models have been marked for use with this plugin.

Currently, I am marking the models in the fashion of `acts_as_something` method which is added to each Model intended to be used with the plugin.

The main file of the plugin looks like this

```
# lib/foo.rb
module Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :models
  end
  self.models = []

  module Model
    def acts_as_foo
      Foo.models << self
    end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  extend Foo::Model
end
```

The intended use is to then call in a controller `Foo.perform`, which needs to know the marked models in order to carry out the intended action, the idea being getting the list of models from `Foo.models`.

It works as intended if when `config.eager_load` is set to true in `development.rb` , otherwise the files of the models have not been used/loaded yet and therefore `Foo.models` is an empty Array.

My goal is to be able to add more models to Foo without having to change Foo's code like this.

```
#app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_foo
end
```

Any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem before in my gem](https://github.com/jrpolidario/quickery/blob/master/lib/quickery/railtie.rb).

I ended up loading **ONLY** model files (which is the minimum of my requirement same as yours because the DSL code is there like your `acts_as_foo`), and not immediately eager loading all Rails-related files using `Rails.application.eager_load!`.

```
# lib/foo.rb
module Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :models
  end

  self.models = []

  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer 'foo.eager_load_models' do |app|
      unless app.config.eager_load
        models_load_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'models')

        # copied from https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Engine/eager_load%21/class
        matcher = /\A#{Regexp.escape(models_load_path.to_s)}\/(.*)\.rb\Z/
        Dir.glob("#{models_load_path}/**/*.rb").sort.each do |file|
          app.require_dependency file.sub(matcher, '\1')
        end
      end
    end
  end

  module Model
    def acts_as_foo
      Foo.models << self
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  extend Foo::Model
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to work with the Railstie, but I need to reference/use my module by name first so that it works. Do you need to run some sort of initializer with this approach?

Comment: Yes, if you're changing lib/foo.rb file to make use of Railstie, I'll update my answer. And yes, you can either create your own initializer file or make use of `config.after_initialize do |app|`

Comment: I just updated my answer to make use of Railstie. Untested, but I think this should already work :)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I extracted the lib code to a gem and it worked without having to run any initializer, but simply requiring Foo::Railstie where the models are loaded with the code you provided.

Comment: No problem! :))